# List service as failing only after a certain duration

Tags: debian, nagios, unattended-upgrades

My Debian systems have `unattended-upgrades` installed, which installs security upgrades automatically, once per day. I also have a Nagios check that reports whether upgrades need to be installed.

In this setup, it is normal that this check can report a failing state, but not for longer than 24h. Can I configure Nagios to consider a service as “up” unless it has been failing for more than 24h?

(`retry_interval` only seems to affect when I get a notification, but I also don't want the front-end to be red during these expected failures.)

Comment: Would a warning state be acceptable?

Comment: In other words, does the nagios upgrade-check script only return OK and ERROR (or fail, I forget), or could it return warning until hour 25? Which part are you trying to do — change the script behavior or change nagios’ reaction to the existing script?

Comment: I’d like to avoid modifying the existing script, so the latter.

Comment: The script returns a hard failure, then?

Comment: What is this service’s check_interval?

Comment: The default of `normal_check_interval 5`; I guess changing that would make sense for this check anyways.